# How to unit test this method (uses clipboard and file-system)?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have an explorer like component, which actually deals with the file system. How do I begin writing unit tests to methods such as these, which require use of clipboard, and actual moving or coping of files in the file system?

I tried looking at tutorials and online courses but they are too abstract and couldn't really help me on my current issue.

```
public void DoCtrlV(object obj)
{
    try
    {
        StopWait();
        var list = System.Windows.Clipboard.GetFileDropList();
        if (list.Count > 0) // i.e. from outside - get file list
        {
            if (!PasteFromOutsideSucceeded(list))
                return;
        }
        else // i.e. from inside
        {
            string targetFolder = GetTargetFolder();

            if (Globals.ListInternalUseCopy != null) // from list
            {
                PasteFromList(targetFolder);
            }
            else if (Globals.TreeInternalUseCopy != null) // from tree
            {
                PasteFromTree(targetFolder);
            }
        }

        RefreshBothControls();
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
    {
        // doesn't matter atm
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT/UPDATE**: There were many things I had to do, and I'm still mid point, but this is what I did so far.

1. I extracted all the testable code into a separate class, outside of the window code-behind were it resided before (really bad place to test things, as you need to instantiate the window to actually test). I passed to it in the constructor all the necessary objects it needed to run.

My DoCtrlV now looks like this:

```
StopWait();
var list = System.Windows.Clipboard.GetFileDropList();
var result = _hadnler.PerformPaste(Globals.ListInternalUseCopy, Globals.TreeInternalUseCopy, list, MoveNotCopy, shellList.Path, shellTree.SelectedPath);
if (!result)
    MessageBox.Show("Please select a destiantion.");
RefreshBothControls();
```

And the only thing I'm testing (atm) is _hadnler.PerformPaste.

2. As you can see, I decided to ignore clipboard and other factors right now, and just focus on the FileSystem operations. My PerformPaste now looks like this:

   ```
   public bool PerformPaste(List<string> listInternalUseCopy, string treeInternalUseCopy, StringCollection clipboardList, bool moveNotCopy, string listPath, string treePath)
   {
       if (clipboardList.Count > 0) // i.e. from outside - get file list
       {
           if (!PasteFromOutsideSucceeded(clipboardList, listPath))
               return false;
       }
       else // i.e. from inside
       {
           string targetFolder = GetTargetFolder(listPath, treePath);

           if (listInternalUseCopy != null) // from list
           {
               PasteFromList(targetFolder, moveNotCopy);
           }
           else if (treeInternalUseCopy != null) // from tree
           {
               PasteFromTree(targetFolder, moveNotCopy);
           }
       }
       return true;
   }
   ```
3. My PerformPaste still calls the sub-methods, but now they are all "Ok". In the end the main problem is that you get to a File.Move or File.Copy - and so that's why I needed something to handle it. So I installed the System.IO.Abstractions NuGet package, and changed my code to support the IFileSystem (basically replaced all IO calls by appending in the beginning my new IFileSystem object calls). In the actual code, it is being set to the regular filesystem, and in the testcode, it a mock filesystem (also supported by a child NuGet Package called System.IO.Abstractions.TestingHelpers).

My Testing code now looks like this:

```
public class MainLogicHandlerTests
{
    private readonly MockFileSystem fileSystem;

    public MainLogicHandlerTests()
    {
        fileSystem = new MockFileSystem(new Dictionary<string, MockFileData>
        {
            { @"c:\src\file1.txt", new MockFileData("Test1") },
            { @"c:\src\file2.txt", new MockFileData("Test2") },
            { @"c:\dst\file3.txt", new MockFileData("Test3") }
        });
        FileSystem.UsedFileSystem = fileSystem;
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void PasteOneFile_FromOutsideIntoList_ShouldSucceed()
    {
        //Arrange
        List<string> listInternal = new List<string>() { @"c:\src\file1.txt"};
        string treeInternal = null;
        StringCollection clipboardList = new StringCollection();
        clipboardList.Add(@"c:\src\file1.txt");
        bool moveNotCopy = false;
        string listPath = @"c:\dst";
        string treePath = @"c:\dst";

        //Act
        var sut = new MainLogicHandler(null);
        var result = sut.PerformPaste(listInternal, treeInternal, clipboardList, moveNotCopy, listPath, treePath);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(fileSystem.FileExists(@"c:\dst\file1.txt"));
    }
}
```

So still a long way to go, but at-least that's a start. Will appreciate any more tips you guys have...

Comment: That completely depends on what you actually want to test. There´s no magic option to test a method, every test is very specific for exactly one single scenario. In particular a scenario is determined by the number of branches in your m,ethod, in your case I can see at least 8. Depending on what the methods you´re calling actually do the complexity of your test may increase rapidly.

Comment: This question is far too broad and [lacking effort](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). I'd suggest you start by reading some unit testing tutorials and maybe pick a unit testing framework (of which there are many)

Comment: @HimBromBeere I would like to test most possible scenarios. For example, test if paste is done from outside, that the PasteFromOutsideSucceeded is actually called, and that the paste is succeeded. But how do I mock the clipboard? And how do I mock a copy of files in the file system ?

Comment: Encapsulate the code that interacts with the system into it's own class with an interface that you inject through the constructor of your class.

Then, when you unit test it, you can either mock or provide a test implementation instead of using the implementation that actually interacts with the system.

Comment: @Liam that dependency injection has nothing to do with unit testing is absurd

Comment: Most scenarios? You see that this might get pretty broad?

Comment: @Novaterata No, they are independent, although DI can be used in unit-testing it doesn´t have to.

Comment: @AlexandreBeaudet because how do we know it's a draft and not an incomplete answer? There is no way to tell.

Comment: @AlexandreBeaudet See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289713/is-it-okay-to-ask-a-question-draft-and-then-afterwards-edit-it to see, why answering in drafts is considered a bad thing. Although it handles the question, the same rules apply for answeres as well.

Comment: DI is a way to decouple code (full stop). That can aid in unit testing but you can unit test without DI and you can DI without unit testing. The two are essentially unrelated

Comment: @Novaterata can you show me how to do so in this example method in my question?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Thanks for the link, I'll check it out, was mainly basing my point on the [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page, especially the "Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful". I'll delete all the comments about that since it's not related to the question in a few minutes

Comment: @AlexandreBeaudet Sorry, I don't have time right now, but I actually think my comment should give you enough to do it yourself. All of the calls to the system or the Globals should be encapsulated into their own class and injected through the constructor or a property, so that you can write other code that just returns the same type of data. As Liam confirms, this is an "aid in unit testing". lol Good day people

Comment: Or you could read [this answer that covers it quite succinctly](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/140992/is-dependency-injection-essential-for-unit-testing/140994#140994) @Evk I wrote unit tests long before DI frameworks became popular.

Comment: @DavidRefaeli don't be intimidated by DI frameworks, you can just inject manually as Kyle's answer without going down that rabbit hole, and just because alternatives are possible, doesn't mean they are wise. In the C# and Java world, you will be expected to inject external dependencies and mock them in unit tests, either manually or using a DI or mocking framework.

Comment: @Liam you are nitpicking. Is there any reason nowadays to unit test code in question without dependency injection techniques, for example with signleton approach described by your link? I doubt that.

Comment: What exactly is your point @Evk? Are you saying unit testing is DI? If your telling me that DI aids unit testing then I agree and [I have already stated this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50155078/how-to-unit-test-this-method-uses-clipboard-and-file-system?noredirect=1#comment87328005_50155078). I'm not going to answer this question because I feel it is too broad. Feel free to add your answer? If your just picking a fight then have fun I have work to do

Comment: @DavidRefaeli, just a note, in your test, I would make the line: string treePath = @"c:\dst"; point to somwhere else so you can tell if the logic puts your file somewhere else (since it's supposed to use the listPath if it works correctly).  Both your listPath and treePath are the same so you can't tell if it uses the wrong one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I usually do to unit test things like this.
Get the code that is dependent on non-unit-testable stuff out of my method.

For example, System.Windows.Clipboard.GetFileDropList is out of your control and should not be unit tested (it is an external dependency).  In order to keep this out of your unit test, you need to use dependency-injection.

Create an interface similar to this:

```
public interface IClipboard
{
    StringCollection GetClipBoardInfo();
}
```

Inject a class that inherits from this into the DoCtrlV method.

```
public void DoCtrlV(object obj, IClipboard clipboard)
```

Create a class that implements the interface version of the method and returns the proper clipboard function:

```
public StringCollection GetClipBoardInfo()
{
  System.Windows.Clipboard.GetFileDropList(); 
}
```

Now, create a class for unit testing that just returns a StringCollection and tells you if the method was called or not.

```
public MockClipboard
{
  public StringCollection GetClipBoardInfo()
  {
    ClipboardWasRead = true;

    StringCollection col = new StringCollection();
    col.Add("...");

    return col;
  }

  public bool ClipboardWasRead { get; set; }
}
```

This way you are not unit testing stuff that is not in your control (like the clipboard and file system).  If you want to test whether your method reads the clipboard or not, you can test on the method's ClipboardWasRead boolean.  **What's really important here is that you are going to need to rewrite your method to be more unit testable.**  The code you have written now has a lot of outside dependencies, like:

- System.Windows.Clipboard.GetFileDropList
- PasteFromOutsideSucceeded
- RefreshBothControls

Just work on them one at a time until you feel comfortable that your code is testable to your liking.

Here is an example test that will tell you if your method actually attempted to read the clipboard or not.

```
[TestMethod]
public void WasClipboardRead()
{
  // Arrange
  var mock = new MockClipboard();
  var obj = new Object();

  // Act
  DoCtrlV(obj, mock);

  // Assert
  Assert.IsTrue(mock.ClipboardWasRead);
}
```

Comment: This seems like a good start. I'll try it and get back to you

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I meant

Comment: @DavidRefaeli, make sure to let us know how it worked out

Comment: @KyleB I accepted your answer, but could you please go over my update and see if you have any comments? Thanks